# C# 自作DLLをStaticで作成した場合のVBAで使用する方法

Tags: c#, vba, dll

お世話になります。

大変情けない話で申し訳ないのですが、C#にて自作のDLLを作成し、VBA側で使用するまでは
たどり着いたのですが、C#側でStaticで宣言したクラスをDLLで呼び出す文法が解りません。

```
   public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {

        }

        public string getMsg()
        {
            return "Hello World.";
        }
    }
```

↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim a As Sample.Class1
    Set a = New Sample.Class1
    MsgBox a.getMsg
End Sub
```

これは解りました。

```
public static class Class1
{

    public static string getMsg()
    {
        return "Hello World.";
    }
}
```

↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

これが解りません。

MsgBox Sample.Class1.getMsgとしてみましたが、ダメでした。

初歩的な質問で申し訳ありませんが、何卒よろしく
お願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

クラスとメソッドの両方をstaticにすることは出来ないようです。
[Can I call a static method of a C# class from VBA via COM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24193183/9014308)

上記記事の回答には、COMとして登録可能な形にして、その中に static method を含める方法を取るようです。以下のようになるのでは？
これで呼び出せるかどうかは確かめていませんが。

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[ComVisible(true)]
public class Class1
{
    [ComVisible(false)]
    public static string getMsg()
    {
        return "Hello World.";
    }

    // staticなmethodのみだとビルドで警告が残るので、ダミーでも何かstaticではないものを追加
    public string getLastMsg()
    {
        return "Bye.";
    }
}
```

---

訂正追記：

元記事を読み直すとやはり直接は呼び出せないようなので、おそらく以下になるのでしょう。

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[ComVisible(true)]
public class Class1
{
    [ComVisible(false)]
    public static string getMsg()
    {
        return "Hello World.";
    }

    // staticなmethodをラップして間接的に呼び出す。
    public string getMsgIndirect()
    {
        return getMsg();
    }
}
```

---

それから、用途によっては、以下記事で紹介している何かが使えるかもしれません。
[アドインの開発方法について](https://office-fun.com/develp-o-addin/)

ExcelならC++でXLLというのが比較的簡単にできそうです。
[Excel で DLL にアクセスする](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/client-developer/excel/how-to-access-dlls-in-excel)

Comment: 早速の回答、ありがとうございました。内容の方、確認しました。サポートしていないのなら仕方ありませんね。インスタンスするクラスでラップして対応することにします。ありがとうございました。